# Changing the position of a 2D array in a matrix in C language

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, matrix, row

here is the question :

have a two 2D array

```
int matrix1[4][5]={ {8,5,2,4,3}, {9,6,4,0,4}, {0,1,2,3,4}, {9,9,9,9,9}};
```

Without changing the elements in the row in the matrix1 The sum of the rows will be ordered from smallest to largest. finally I want to transfer it to matrix 2 . cant use copy or functions just the basic programming skills like ( for,array,if, )

matrix2 should look like this:

```
int matrix2[4][5]={{0,1,2,3,4},  {9,6,4,0,4},  {8,5,2,4,3},  {9,9,9,9,9}};
```

here is my code

```
int i, j, temp, plus = 0;
int matris1[4][5] = {
    {8, 5, 2, 4, 3},
    {9, 6, 4, 0, 4},
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    {9, 9, 9, 9, 9}};

int matris2[4][5];
int topla[4];

/*here I found sum of the rows*/

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        plus = plus + matris1[i][j];
    }

    topla[i] = plus;
    plus = 0;
}

/*here I did the smallest to largest and copy to the array topla */
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (topla[i] < topla[j])
        {
            temp = topla[i];
            topla[i] = topla[j];
            topla[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

/* cant transfer to the matrix2 HELP PLEASE :'( */
int k;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        plus = plus + matris1[i][j];
    }

    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
    {
        if (plus == topla[k])
        {
            matris2[k] = matris1[i];
        }
    }

    plus = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("%d - ", matris2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: "matrix2 should look like this"  No it shouldn't, 23 is less than 22.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a struct remembering the sum and a pointer to the corresponding data that gave that sum:

```
typedef struct
{
  int* data;
  int sum;
} sum_t;
```

Then it goes like this:

```
int matrix1[4][5] = { {8,5,2,4,3}, {9,6,4,0,4}, {0,1,2,3,4}, {9,9,9,9,9} };
sum_t sum[4] = {0}; // set everything to zero
for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  sum[i].data = matrix1[i]; // remember which sum this is for later
  for(size_t j=0; j<5; j++) // calculate sum
  {
    sum[i].sum += matrix1[i][j];
  }
}
```

Next you'd call a sort function like `qsort`. But since you can't do that because of artificial requirements, you could just spew out some inefficient, manual version:

```
// school book example of a bad sort function:
void shitty_bubble_sort (size_t n, sum_t arr[n])
{
   for(size_t i=0; i<n-1; i++)
   {
     for(size_t j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
     {
       if(arr[j].sum > arr[j+1].sum)
       {
         sum_t tmp = arr[j];
         arr[j] = arr[j+1];
         arr[j+1] = tmp;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Usage: `shitty_bubble_sort(4,sum);`

That bubble sort function is the same thing you did when sorting `topla`, the only real difference is the loop indices and that I'm moving structs instead of integers.

Then create the next matrix based on the sorted sums:

```
int matrix2[4][5];
for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  shitty_memcpy(&matrix2[i], sum[i].data, sizeof(matrix2[i]));

  printf("{ ");
  for(size_t j=0; j<5; j++)
  {
    printf("%d ", matrix2[i][j]);
  }
  printf("}\n");
}
```

Where `shitty_memcpy` is just like ordinary `memcpy` but slower, for the benefit of your artificial requirments:

```
//school book example of a naive memcpy
void shitty_memcpy (void* dst, const void* src, size_t n)
{
  unsigned char* d = dst;
  const unsigned char* s = src;
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    d[i] = s[i];
  }
}
```

Complete example here: https://godbolt.org/z/ra8jenWWM. If you aren't allowed to use functions at all, then inlining those two functions manually is left as an exercise.

Comment: Lessons learnt: -We learnt how to not write a sorting function. -We learnt how to not write a copy function. -We learnt how to write inefficient, possibly buggy code manually instead of using pre-made, efficient functions from the standard library.